# How can I separate pairs of zeros with delimiter

Tags: python

I get this value when I convert hexadecimal to ascii:

```
output = '0000000000000000'
```

so I need to put a delimiter in each pair of two digits. how can I do this in python?

Comment: Is that a string? What delimiter? *What have you tried?!*

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes is the string. The delimiter can be comma. I tried using the split but without success.

Comment: And what does *"without success"* mean? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> output = '00000000001'
>>> result = ','.join(re.findall(r'.{1,2}', output))
>>> result
'00,00,00,00,00,1'
```

Change `{1,2}` to `{2}` if you want to ignore the remaining character if the number of chars is odd.

Comment: thank you stevieb. I was trying in this way `re.findall('..',output)` but not get the desired result.